# How can 1 Link listen for 2 paths in React-Router-Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this Navigation in my React App:

```
<ul className="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
      Home
    </NavLink>
  </li>  
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink to="/home" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
      Home
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink to="/pictures" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
      Pictures
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink to="/contact" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
      Contact
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Like this there are 4 tabs but I only want 3 - "/" and "/home" both shall highlight the Home-Tab as active..

I'm pretty sure React-Router has something implemented for this case, but I could not find it yet, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of `<Redirect />`:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={() => (
    <Redirect to="/home" />
)}/>
```

This will provide a clear place to identify how the route is used and is eventually ready to be replaced with real content instead of just redirecting.

If you want just to control the active state of `<NavLink />` use `isActive` prop:

```
 isActive={(match, location) => {
         return location.pathname === '/home' || location.pathname === '/';
 }}
```

Comment: Yes the 2nd is what I need, but the other one is pretty interesting, too. Thank you!

Comment: Just tried it, it's actually ```location.pathname === ...``` 
Best answer anyway. (Y)

Comment: @J.Dario fixed, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isActive` prop. It takes an callback which can decide whether this item is active or not

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func

```js
<li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink
      exact
      to="/home"
      className="nav-link"
      activeClassName="active"
      isActive={(match, location) => {
        if (!match) {
          return false;
        }
        return location.path === '/home' || location.path === '/');
      }}
     >
      Home
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, my pc just died, I'll have a more precise look at this later.

Comment: I did not downvote but maybe he did because compared to 
```
isActive={(match, location) => {
  return (
    location.pathname === "/addBooks" || location.pathname === "/"
  );
}}
```
your solution with the if statement in it does not work somehow  and I had to change ```.path``` to ```.pathname```

Comment: Because I just gave you the idea how to achieve this. `location.path` might not be a valid value or undefined